Web server with both Inbound via direct Public IP and Inbound via External Load Balancer
I need to migrate customers pointing to web server by IP to a new solution as Basic IP is retiring. Lack of DNS solution complicates this problem; it will be a manual migration customer by customer.
I'm hoping to maintain the flow of traffic to the Public IP and stand up a Load Balancer as the new inbound route and have them run simultaneously in order to simplify the migration.  I have quickly run into questions that I cant find documentation to answer.  The main challenge appears to be, can the VM take in bound paths from the LB and return the traffic in the correct direction while maintaining the default route for the existing solution?  The straight IP solution that is functional today would need to return traffic through the default path and the LB traffic would need to flow back through the load balancer.
It doesnt look like the LB will support this, the Application Gateway is likely the right tool.  But I only need this solution for two weeks and I'm hoping to find a workaround.
My thoughts have gone to UDR, adding host routes for the customers as they migrate to the LB, but that seems overly difficult and risky.  My thought this morning was a second NIC on the webserver might be the way to go.  Attaching the new NIC to the LB back-end rather than by IP might give me traffic return to the LB and not affect traffic to the NIC bearing the Public IP (needing the default route return).  And that is the area of my ignorance.
I cant seem to find what attaching the NIC to the backend actually does.  I found a description from MS, but the details are not very clear:  "When a backend pool is configured by IP address, it will behave as a Basic Load Balancer with default outbound enabled. For secure by default configuration and applications with demanding outbound needs, configure the backend pool by NIC."  That sounds like it provides the return to LB traffic flow I need, but how does it work?
If anyone can advise, I would appreciate it greatly!  I'm going to run out some testing to see what I can discover.  If anyone can provide links to documentation showing exactly what happens, I'd put you on my Christmas list :)

Did you try this hands on? It should work, adding a public ip and LB will work simultaneously
